# Is there any possible issue with changing the boot order often?

Tags: boot

After going through many Q&As online, I have managed to install Ubuntu 12.04 along with Windows 8.1 (pre-installed). Though, its not complete,  I am happy with it (after trying it for almost 2days). But, I have a question.

Now, when I boot the PC, Windows 8.1 is automatically booted (no prompts to choose OS) and if I want to boot Ubuntu, I need to press f12 (I am using Acer V3-772G) to change the boot order and thus, I am able boot Ubuntu. This approach works perfectly fine for me.

But, I want to switch between Windows and Ubuntu often. My question is,  what are the consequences (or issues) of changing boot order often. will it corrupt my HDD or any other devices.

My PC configuration:

- 120 SSD: Windows 8.1 (`C:\`)
- 1TB SATA HDD1: `D:\`
- 1TB SATA HDD2:  `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS`

Note: 
I tried `boot-repair` several times with no luck (I am getting `grub-rescue>`). So, I decided not to use that.

Answer (score 3):

Changing the boot order frequently won't have any bad effect on your hardware, it will not corrupt anything.

Answer (score 0):

Put your Ubuntu HDD on top in your boot order list in the BIOS. After powering the pc, you should see the grub OS list, and you can choose which OS to boot. If you don't see that purple screen and the pc boots automatically to Ubuntu, try `sudo update-grub2` on the command line of Ubuntu, to install grub to the MBR. (it won't corrupt any drives)

Answer (score -1):

You can use an easy-to-use the GUI application called [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer) to make your life a little bit easier. As the name suggests, you can do much more than just reordering GRUB menu entries with it.

You can install it by:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

[image: screen_2]

[source](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/43471/how-to-configure-the-linux-grub2-boot-menu-the-easy-way/)

**Another Method(CLI)**

## 1: Determine the order of the OS you’d like to boot in GRUB

Restart your computer. When it boots again, press one of the directional keys (up or down) when the GRUB menu appears. Write down the line number of the OS you’d like to boot(start from 0)

## 2: Open the GRUB config file using the terminal

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Locate the GRUB_DEFAULT setting. Delete the value that appears there (by default, 0) and replace it with the number you wrote down in step #1.

Once you’re done, save the document and close it.

## 3: Update GRUB

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: That probably won't do the trick, as his windows drive is the main boot device.